# I have an issue with images not rendering even when using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// atom.js

export const cropPath = atom({
  key: "cropPath",
  default: []
});

export const prevImgState = atom({
  key: "prevImgState",
  default: []
});

export const croppedImgState = atom({
  key: "croppedImgState",
  default: []
});

// TopMenu.jsx

const cropPaths = useRecoilValue(cropPath);
const setImageFilesState = useSetRecoilState(prevImgState);


const [autoSiTiVisible, setAutoSiTiVisible] = useState(false);

const handleCalculatingAutoSiTiClick = () => {
      setAutoSiTiVisible(true);
};


 const readDir = (dirPath) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(dirPath, (err, files) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            const allFiles = [];
            const promises = [];

            files.forEach((item) => {
              let newPath = path.join(dirPath, item);

              promises.push(
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  fs.stat(newPath, (err, stats) => {
                    if (err) {
                      reject(err);
                    } else {
                      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                        readDir(newPath)
                          .then((subFiles) => {
                            allFiles.push(...subFiles);
                            resolve();
                          })
                          .catch(reject);
                      } else {
                        allFiles.push(newPath);
                        resolve();
                      }
                    }
                  });
                })
              );
            });

            Promise.all(promises)
              .then(() => {
                resolve(allFiles);
              })
              .catch(reject);
          }
        });
      });
    };
    const fetchImageFiles = async (dirPath) => {
      try {
        const allFiles = await readDir(dirPath);
        console.log("allFiles: ", allFiles);
        return allFiles;
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    };

    const processDirectory = async () => {
      try {
        const allFiles = await fetchImageFiles(cropPaths[0]);
        setImageFilesState(allFiles);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      processDirectory();
    }, [cropPaths[0]]);

return (
<>
 <Button onClick={handleCalculatingAutoSiTiClick}>AUTO SITI</Button>
{autoSiTiVisible && (
          <WidthHeightInputModal
            visible={autoSiTiVisible}
            onCancel={() => setAutoSiTiVisible(false)}
            onConfirm={autoCalculateSiTi}
          />
        )}
</>
)

// SegmentList.jsx

const imageFilesStates = useRecoilValue(prevImgState);

....

return (
<CroppedImageViewer
  prevImg={imageFilesStates}
...
/>
)

// CroppedImageViewer.jsx

import { Button, Image, Modal, Popover } from "antd";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const CroppedImageViewer = ({
  prevImg,
....
}) => {
  console.log("prevImg", prevImg);



export default CroppedImageViewer;
```

In the TopMenu.jsx file, set the

cropPaths[0] is a value of type string called 'xxxx/1/splitted_1' and we used a function called readDir to navigate to the subfolders within this splitted_1 folder.

And to get the images inside the subfolders, we want to use the fetchImageFiles function and the processDirectory function to fetch the images.

The issue I'm currently having is that I'm getting an error within the processDirectory function, even though I've conditioned it with `typeof cropPaths[0]==='string'`.

Also, when I use useEffect, the result is the same.

When I console check the imageFilesStates in SegmentList.jsx, it is initially an empty array, but when I press Ctrl+s (save code) once more in TopMenu.jsx, the imageFilesStates are showing as values filled with a list of images.

I would like to know what is wrong

Comment: I solved. I deleted useEffect and switched from code calling the API to using the processDirectory function.